# How to replace an avatar image from a form with an url input?

Tags: javascript, html

how can i change the avatar image of my page when i fill the form? i'm still new with js so i don't know a lot of stuff, i'm studying it

```html
 
<div class="profile__avatar-overlay">
  <img class="profile__avatar" src="my-img" alt="Аvatar">
  <button type="submit" class="profile__edit-button"></button>
</div>

<form class="form" id="form-avatar">
  <button type="button" class="popup__close"></button>
  <p class="form__text">Edit Profile</p>
 <label class="form__field">
  <input type="url" placeholder="New image url" id='url-avatar' class="form__input" value="" required>
  <span id="url-avatar-error" class="form__input-error"></span>
 </label>
  <button type="submit" class="form__submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

I was trying this function but nothing happen in the page. I tried

```js
function changeAvatar() {
  const inputAvatarValue = formAvatarInput.value;
  profileAvatar.src = inputAvatarValue;
    
  return changeAvatar;
};

formUpdateAvatar.addEventListener('submit', changeAvatar);
```

Comment: in your code you didn't initialize the variables `formAvatarInput`, `inputAvatarValue`, `formUpdateAvatar`; you are returning a value inside a submit event handler (there's no reason to do that); you are not doing any preventDefault() in your event handler so the form will be submitted before you can see any change made to the page; you said you want to change the picture when the form was filled but the event you used was `submit` that gets fired when you click the submit button

Comment: your comment was very helpful, the variables were imported from another js file, the problem was that in my function there was no preventDefault()

Comment: to make it work you need your event handler to have the event parameter so you can call event.preventDefault();